# Remove underline from react-native TextInput

Tags: react-native

I want to remove the underline of a TextInput of my react-native application. I tried with borderBottomWidth but it did not work. How can I achieve this on Android and IOS.

Comment: `underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'}` might be the one. Use it as props of `TextInput`

Comment: Can you add the code and the styles for the issue?

Comment: @_Ravi @_Pritish, the issue was fixed as Ravi suggested. IOS doesn't have a default underline so handling android fixed the issue. Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its really simple

In **iOS** we dont have underline.

and for **android** just add this prop

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid={'rgba(0,0,0,0)'}> </TextInput>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
```

by this you can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `borderWidth: 0`

Example:

```
<TextInput 
  style={{borderWidth: 0}}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found in code inspection is on the TextInput, you could use the :

```
inputContainerStyle={{borderBottomWidth:0}}
```

Comment: This is no longer part of the API.